# GPU running "Very High" during render

Tags: rendering

Starting yesterday, 2.8 began running very 'hot' on my GPU. Task manager shows GPU running between 98 and 100%. In fact when clicking render view in the view port, the program has begun crashing - regularly, like almost every time.
This is sudden. I've never had this problem with any version of blender. Not sure if it's Windows 10 (which I strongly suspect) or a bug in blender.
Is anyone else experiencing this problem? Any suggestions/solutions?
Thanks very much.

Blender 2.8 ran perfectly until yesterday. Both the Beta and the "stable". 2.79 ran without a hitch as well. At this point it doesn't matter what I'm doing. Whether in the view port or rendering, the program's performance drags;the task manager fluctuates between low, high, and very high (100%) GPU usage. I did a windows 10 reset an hour ago, in the hopes that, that would fix the problem. I performed a fresh install of 2.8, but still it's slow and crashes. Again, I've never had a problem like this with Blender. I've always been impressed by it's stability. So, this all comes as a bit of a shock.

Comment: Did you use Blender 2.8 before without encountering any issues? Is the GPU usage that high when just using the interface or during rendering?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes Blender 2.8 ran perfectly until yesterday. Both the Beta and the "stable". 2.79 ran without a hitch as well. At this point it doesn't matter what I'm doing. Whether in the view port or rendering, the program's performance drags;the task manager fluctuates between low, high, and very high (100%) GPU usage. I did a windows 10 reset an hour ago, in the hopes that, that would fix the problem. I performed a fresh install of 2.8, but still it's slow and crashes.
Again, I've never had a problem like this with Blender. I've always been impressed by it's stability. So, this a

Comment: Did you make sure the GPU drivers are up to date? Wrong GPU drivers could cause this. Or it could even be that Windows updated them automatically to a version containing some bug. What is the GPU model in question? Could you maybe edit the question and provide the specs for the PC? That might be helpful.